# jQuery Autocomplete - When an item is selected from the list store it in a php variable

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

Once someone selects an item from the list of autocomplete options, how can I store the id of that item as a variable to be used in other php scripts?

Current PHP Script:

```
$rs = mysql_query('select label, id from table where label like     "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" order by label asc limit 0,10', $dblink);

$data = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => $row['label'] ,
            'value' => $row['id']
        );
    }
}

echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```

My goal is to use the id variable as a placeholder for table names

Comment: which autocomplete plugin are you using ????

Comment: what precisely do you want to do after an item is selected?

Comment: I would like to store the id for the selected item in a variable that I could use in the place of a table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script for getting ID for auto complete values

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(function() {

            $('#location').val("");

            $("#location").autocomplete({
                source: "getLocation.php",
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $('#locationid').val(ui.item.id);


                }
            });


        });

</script>
```

### pass the ID in hidden

```
<form action="" method="post" name="addvendor" id="addvendor">
<label>Location:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="location" id="location" /><span id="locationInfo"></span>
                        <input type="hidden" name="locationid" id="locationid" />
</form>
```

get page for getting values of location and id

---

```
<?php
include('../config/config.php');

$return_arr = array();

/* If connection to database, run sql statement. */


    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT location_id,location_name FROM location where location_name like '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']) . "%'");

    /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['id'] = $row['location_id'];
        $row_array['value'] = $row['location_name'];
        //$row_array['abbrev'] = $row['country_id'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }





echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

Note:
include the js file bootstrap.min.js
for styles

---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jensbits.com/demos/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
```

for more information use the link
http://www.jensbits.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 2):

Huh?  Php runs on the server, JavaScript/jQuery runs on the client.  You can't directly set any php variables from JavaScript.

However, if you make an AJAX call to the server and include the selected item id as a parameter, the server can then note the selected id (for instance, as part of the current user session) and refer back to it on subsequent requests.

Comment: Would you elaborate on how to do so or provide a link of an example if possible?